# XML XSLT to HTML write text in textarea and keep this content

Tags: html, xml, xslt, textarea

I try to describe my problem. I have a XML with data from a test. This XML will be transformed by XSL. I have inserted an href to the *.xsl, so when I open the XML i will see the XML in HTML format. Now i want to comment the results in a textarea.

I have inserted a textarea after each test-section to comment the results. This works so far, but how can i keep the typed text in the textarea? Even if I save the file(XML) as HTML the textarea is still be empty.

Sorry for my English, i am not a native speaker

Comment: i can define an extra (empty) comment-element in the XML. Can i write the typed text from the textarea back to the XML in the defined element?

Comment: Do you load the XML into a browser like Firefox, IE, Chrome? Do you load the XML from a HTTP server or do you load it from the local file system?

Comment: Yes i load the XML into a browser (IE11). Both, right after the test i want to comment locally and then it goes on Sharepoint "online"

Comment: If you want to edit XML in the browser then I would check out existing solutions like http://www.lexiconista.com/xonomy/ or others listed on http://www.lexiconista.com/xonomy/web-based-xml-editors/. Textarea based editing is rather awkward.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution, you could use html5 localstorage to save your comments.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Here is an example See https://jsfiddle.net/hgdod21p/

HTML

```
<h2>Text Area here</h2>

<textarea id="foo" title="tab out of the field to save changes">
</textarea>
```

JavaScript to Save/Retrieve from local storage

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#foo").val(localStorage.getItem("foo"));
    $("#foo").bind("blur", function(){
      var val = $('#foo').val();
      localStorage.setItem('foo', val);
      alert("Saved: " + localStorage.getItem("foo"));
    });
});
```

This solution will save text within your browser.  To persist the comments beyond your browser, you could use some additional javascript to generate a dump of comment text.